# Adding a region to the individual item pages under a node in the gallery assist module

Tags: blocks, theming, paging, media

I'm trying to force a region into the individual item pages of a node that's using the gallery assist module to be able to display blocks.

I started off making a context and adding the gallery assist content type the context to be able to blocks to the nodes of gallery

but the regions only being added to the main node page and not being added to the individual items pages under the node

for example:

www.testsite.com/gallery-type/main-node-page-title - This is the main node gallery item page looks

www.testsite.com/gallery-type/main-node-page-title/image1 - And this is how the individual items pages under the node are setup

www.testsite.com/gallery-type/main-node-page-title/image2

www.testsite.com/gallery-type/mmain-node-page-title/image3

so is there anyway a region can be added to the individual item pages programmatically, in the admin area or module wise?

This is also the output for the individual item pages:

```
function theme_gallery_assist_item($item = array()) {    

  $output .= ' <div class="clear-block gallery-assist-item-container">'."\n";
  $output .= '   <div id="node-'. $item->nid .'" class="node">'."\n";

  $output .= '   <div class="inner">'."\n";
  $output .= '   <div class=""><h1 class="title">'. $item->title .'</h1></div>'."\n";

  $output .= '  <div class="clear-block">'. $item->links .'</div>'."\n";

  $output .= '     </div>'."\n";

  $output .= '     <div class="content clear-block">'."\n";
  if ($item->top == 1 || $item->top == 3) {

   $output .= '       <div id="ga-pager" class="'. $item->nodetype .' ga-pager clear-block">'. $item->pager .'</div>'."\n";
  }

$output .= '       <div id="ga-image-display" class="'. $item->nodetype .' ga-image-display" style="'. $item->size_parameters .';'. $item->extra_styles . $item->img_extra_styles .'">'."\n";

  $output .= $_GET['links'] == 'on' ? $item->adm_link : '';

  $output .= $item->img;

  $output .= '</div>';
  if ($item->top == 0 || $item->top == 3) $output .= '       <div id="ga-pager" class="'. $item->nodetype .' ga-pager clear-block">'. $item->pager .'</div>'."\n";

  $output .= empty($item->copyright) ? '' : '       <div id="gallery-item-copyright" class="'. $item->nodetype .' gallery-item-copyright" style="'. $item->boxes_width .';'. $item->extra_styles .'">&copy; '. $item->copyright .'</div>'."\n";
  if ($item->ptitle) {

  $output .= '       <div id="gallery-item-caption-title" class="'. $item->nodetype .' gallery-item-caption-title" style="'. $item->boxes_width .';'. $item->extra_styles .'">'. $item->ptitle .'</div>'."\n";
  }
  if ($item->pdescription) {

  $output .= '       <div id="gallery-item-caption-text" class="'. $item->nodetype .' gallery-item-caption-text" style="'. $item->boxes_width .';'. $item->extra_styles .'">'. $item->pdescription .'</div>'."\n";
  }
  if ($item->allow_download == 1) {

  $output .= '       <div id="gallery-item-download-link" class="'. $item->nodetype .' gallery-item-download-link" style="'. $item->boxes_width .';'. $item->extra_styles .'"><a href="'. $item->download_path .'">Download</a></div>'."\n";
  }


  $output .= '     </div>'."\n";
  $output .= '   </div>'."\n";
  $output .= ' </div>'."\n";
  return $output;
}
```